# SqlAlchemy: array of Postgresql custom types

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

So in my postgres DB I have the following custom type:

```
create type my_pg_type as (  
    sting_id varchar(32),
    time_diff interval,
    multiplier integer
);
```

To further complicate things, this is being used as an array:

```
alter table my_table add column my_keys my_pg_type [];
```

I'd like to map this with SQLAlchemy (0.6.4) !!

(apologies for elixir)

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.types import Enum
from elixir import Entity, Field    

class MyTable(Entity):
    # -- snip --
    my_keys = Field(ARRAY(Enum))
```

I know 'Enum' is incorrect in the above.

For an example of a value coming back from the database for that array column, I've shown below the value in `ARRAY.result_processor(self, dialect, coltype)`:

```
class ARRAY(sqltypes.MutableType, sqltypes.Concatenable, sqltypes.TypeEngine):
    # -- snip --  
    def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
        item_proc = self.item_type.result_processor(dialect, coltype)
        if item_proc:
            def convert_item(item):
                if isinstance(item, list):
                    return [convert_item(child) for child in item]
                else:
                    return item_proc(item)
        else:
            def convert_item(item):
                if isinstance(item, list):
                    return [convert_item(child) for child in item]
                else:
                    return item
        def process(value):
            if value is None:
                return value
            """
            # sample value:
             >>> value
            '{"(key_1,07:23:00,0)","(key_2,01:00:00,20)"}'
            """
            return [convert_item(item) for item in value]
        return process
```

So the above `process` function incorrectly splits the string, assuming it's already a list.

So far, I've successfully subclassed ARRAY to properly split the string, and instead of Enum, I've tried to write my own type (implementing Unicode) to recreate the `(string, timedelta, integer)` tuple, but have run into a lot of difficulties, specifically the proper conversion of the `interval` to the Python `timedelta`.

I'm posting here in case I'm missing an obvious precedent way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE** See the recipe at the bottom for a workaround

I worked up some example code to see what psycopg2 is doing here, and this is well within their realm - psycopg2 is not interpreting the value as an array at all.    psycopg2 needs to be able to parse out the ARRAY when it comes back as SQLA's ARRAY type assumes at least that much has been done.  You can of course hack around SQLAlchemy's ARRAY, which here would mean basically not using it at all in favor of something that parses out this particular string value psycopg2 is giving us back.

But what's also happening here is that we aren't even getting at psycopg2's mechanics for converting timedeltas either, something SQLAlchemy normally doesn't have to worry about.  In this case I feel like the facilities of the DBAPI are being under-utilized and psycopg2 is a very capable DBAPI.

So I'd advise you work with psycopg2's custom type mechanics over at http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#database-types-casting-functions.

If you want to mail their [mailing list](http://mail.postgresql.org/mj/mj_wwwusr/domain=postgresql.org?func=lists-long-full&extra=psycopg), here's a test case:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database="test", user="scott", password="tiger")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
create type my_pg_type as (  
    string_id varchar(32),
    time_diff interval,
    multiplier integer
)
""")

cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE my_table (
        data my_pg_type[]
    )
""")

cursor.execute("insert into my_table (data) "
            "values (CAST(%(data)s AS my_pg_type[]))", 
            {'data':[("xyz", "'1 day 01:00:00'", 5), ("pqr", "'1 day 01:00:00'", 5)]})

cursor.execute("SELECT * from my_table")
row = cursor.fetchone()
assert isinstance(row[0], (tuple, list)), repr(row[0])
```

PG's type registration supports global registration.  You can also register the types on a per-connection basis within SQLAlchemy using the [pool listener](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_6/core/interfaces.html#connection-pool-events) in 0.6 or [connect event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.connect) in 0.7 and further.

**UPDATE** - due to https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3467/array-of-enums-does-not-allow-assigning I'm probably going to recommend people use this workaround type for now, until psycopg2 adds more built-in support for this:

```
class ArrayOfEnum(ARRAY):

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return sa.cast(bindvalue, self)

    def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
        super_rp = super(ArrayOfEnum, self).result_processor(dialect, coltype)

        def handle_raw_string(value):
            inner = re.match(r"^{(.*)}$", value).group(1)
            return inner.split(",")

        def process(value):
            return super_rp(handle_raw_string(value))
        return process
```

Comment: relevant SQLAlchemy issue, I guess the poster here didn't manage to get psycopg2 to add this feature: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3467/array-of-enums-does-not-allow-assigning

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the [sqlalchemy_utils](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/pg_composite.html) documentation:

```
CompositeType provides means to interact with
`PostgreSQL composite types`_. Currently this type features:

* Easy attribute access to composite type fields
* Supports SQLAlchemy TypeDecorator types
* Ability to include composite types as part of PostgreSQL arrays
* Type creation and dropping
```

Usage:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy_utils import Composite, CurrencyType


class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'account'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    balance = sa.Column(
        CompositeType(
            'money_type',
            [
                sa.Column('currency', CurrencyType),
                sa.Column('amount', sa.Integer)
            ]
        )
    )
```

Array Of Composites:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import CompositeArray


class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'account'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    balances = sa.Column(
        CompositeArray(
            CompositeType(
                'money_type',
                [
                    sa.Column('currency', CurrencyType),
                    sa.Column('amount', sa.Integer)
                ]
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Looks good! I'm not in a position to test right now. Any idea when this was added, or if it was added by @zzzeek ?

Comment: this is another project, which extends the sqlalchemy, called: sqlalchemy_utils